# Bootstrap Menu Dropdown not working ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Menu dropdown is not dropping down, nothing happens when clicked.  I have searched all posts and still can not get this working.  I have a dropdown as follows in my asp.net webforms project.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="myAccount" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="bd-versions">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/docs/4.1/">Messages</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/docs/4.1/">Subscription</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/docs/4.0/">Profile</a>
      </div>
</li>
```

jquery-3.3.1 is installed correctly via nuget and referenced prior to bootstrap as follows.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

What am I missing?  Another clue maybe, when I shrink window size and responsive bootstrap menus collapse, the 'burger' when expanded only flashes for a second then collapses on its own.

**Update**:  I added the following CDN references as suggested and it works.  I'm baffled as to the correct way to bundle these scripts in VS17 for jquery bootstrap, and popper.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Again here is my script refs in bundleconfig.cs and now how they are commented out in site.master

```
        // For more information on Bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=303951
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js")
                        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
                        "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

        // Order is very important for these files to work, they have explicit dependencies
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

        // Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/popper").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"));
    }

    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />--%>
```

Would like to know the VS recommended way to do this as I don't like relying on CDN.  thank you

Comment: It is working in Bootstrap `4.1.3`. So check the browser console for errors.

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive with your problem than just _"can not get this working"_? Your markup you provided works fine [here](https://www.bootply.com/ESmuqQ3e5N)

Comment: Who downvotes a question?  I was descript with code examples etc.  It is not dropping down

Comment: @VDWWD I don't get any errors via browser console

Comment: @zgood yes it works in bootstrap that is not my issue, my question revolves around the fact that is not working in asp.net as stated in question.

Comment: There is no difference. Bootstrap is client side. aspnet is server side. Is has nothing to do with the fact that it is asp. In the end it is all just html.

Comment: @VDWWD It has everything to do with asp.net.   I get what you're saying but yes there are many nuances to how the scripts are loaded which can affect functionality.  If there is an issue with jquery and how it is being referenced it will not work, that is why i included my script references.

Comment: @MX313 Can you confirm that its your .net script references by commenting them out and adding CDN references in the `<head>` to jQuery and Bootstrap libraries? Basically take .NET out of the picture, then we can determine if it is your script references and not some some outside CSS or JS interferring with your dropdown

Comment: @zgood I will try that and report. thank you